# HTML/CSS dropdown navigation menu

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

How do I fixed the drop down menu displaying incorrectly and also the material icons being out of place? The height of the nav bar has to be 60px so i tried by displaying in-line block but it is not working... Help!

```css
body {} #nav-main {
  width: 1280px;
  min-width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.39);
  height: 60px;
}
li {
  float: left;
  height: 60px;
}
li a,
li div {
  display: block;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 19px 25px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.search-form {
  width: 550px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 15px 65px;
}
input[type="search"] {
  width: 100%;
  background: url(../images/search-icon.png) no-repeat #fcfcfc;
  border: 1px solid #d1d1d1;
  background-size: contain;
  padding: 3px 15px 3px 30px;
  line-height: 22px;
  text-shadow: 0 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15) inset;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15) inset;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15) inset;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.7s ease 0s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.7s ease 0s;
  -o-transition: all 0.7s ease 0s;
  transition: all 0.7s ease 0s;
}
input[type="search"]:focus {
  width: 300px;
}
i.material-icons {
  font-size: 26px;
}
li a:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.50);
}
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  color: #fff;
}
.dropdown ul {
  z-index: 9;
  top: 101%;
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}
.dropdown:hover ul {
  display: block;
}
.dropdown ul li {
  margin: 0;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul id="nav-main">
  <li>
    <a href="#">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="/about">About</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="/faq">FAQ</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="/Contact">Contact</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <form action="action_page.php" class="search-form">
      <input type="search" name="savanasearch" placeholder="Search..." class="nav-item5">
    </form>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <a href="#"><i class="material-icons">account_circle</i></a>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Login</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Register</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="nav-item"><i class="material-icons">favorite_border</i></a>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Favorites</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Wishlist</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Track Order</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

only saw this question today and wondered if you ever got it sorted.

Here's my tuppence

```css
body {} 
#nav-main {
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.39);
  height: 60px;
}
li {
  float: left;
  height: 60px;
}
li a{display: block;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 19px 25px;
  text-decoration: none;}
li div {
  display:block!important;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.search-form {
  width: 550px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 15px 50px;
}
input[type="search"] {
  width: 80%;
  background: url(../images/search-icon.png) no-repeat #fcfcfc;
  border: 1px solid #d1d1d1;
  background-size: contain;
  padding: 3px 15px 3px 30px;
  line-height: 22px;
  text-shadow: 0 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15) inset;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15) inset;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15) inset;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.7s ease 0s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.7s ease 0s;
  -o-transition: all 0.7s ease 0s;
  transition: all 0.7s ease 0s;
}
input[type="search"]:focus {
  width: 300px;
}
i.material-icons {
  font-size: 26px;
}
li a:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.50);
}
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: -10px;
  margin-left:-50px;
  padding-left:15px;
  color: #fff;
}
.dropdown ul {
  position: relative;
  display: none;
}
.dropdown:hover ul {
  display: block!important;
}
.dropdown ul li {
  display: block!important;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.39);
  float:none!important;
}
```

```html
<body>
<ul id="nav-main">
  <li>
    <a href="#">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="/about">About</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="/faq">FAQ</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="/Contact">Contact</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <form action="action_page.php" class="search-form">
      <input type="search" name="savanasearch" placeholder="Search..." class="nav-item5">
    </form>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <a href="#"><i class="material-icons">account_circle</i></a>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Login</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Register</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="nav-item"><i class="material-icons">favorite_border</i></a>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Favorites</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Wishlist</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Track Order</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
</body>
```

psst.. look at it full screen!